# how to redirect external requests?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to configure Apache using `.htaccess` file so that any request from external web page should be redirected to `splash.html` but internal request should be not redirected for example :

if i'm on `www.test.com` and I clicked a link that leads to `www.mysite.com` it should redirect to  `www.mysite.com/splash.html` but if I request `www.mysite.com` from `wwww.mysite/com/products` it should take me to `www.mysite.com/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your .htaccess like:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://([^.]+\.)*mysite\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /splash.html [R,NC]
```

Taking in mind you may come from any subdomain under your website, but if you want to restrict that to only one domain then:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.mysite.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /splash.html [R,NC]
```

You can test that [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Update1:

Note: I assume you are using Linux, if you are using Windows, please look to end of my comment first.

I recommend you to isolate your project on localhost by doing the following:

1- putting your project in specific path, let's say in /var/www/test/, where that path contains .htaccess

2- Create Apache virtual host, by creating /etc/apache/sites-enabled/mysite.conf, contains the following:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/test
     <Directory /var/www/test>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride All
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

3- Add this line to end of your /etc/hosts:

```
    127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com mysite.com
```

4- Restart Apache

According to the above, you can run on your local code, using this URL(s):

```
    mysite.com 
    www.mysite.com
```

And do whatever tests you want locally without affecting your other projects running under

```
    localhost
```

I tested the above logic by creating simple html page http://localhost/test.html contains hyperlink to mysite.com/test.html

Note:
If you are using Windows, you can do the following replacements:

```
/var/www/ => Apache root of your local server
/etc/hosts => c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
/etc/apache/sites-enabled => virtual hosts of your local server
```

Update2:

In case you don't like to go with virtual host stuff above

1- Create folder on your apache root, let's name it "mysite"

2- Inside mysite put this .htaccess

```
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://localhost/mysite/ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /splash.html [R,NC]
```

3- You can test redirection using test.html outside of "mysite" folder, with this code

```
    <a href="http://localhost/mysite/test.html">test</a>
```

4- You can test internal pages are working fine using test.html inside "mysite" folder, with this code

```
    <a href="http://localhost/mysite/test.html">test</a>
```

Comment: It looks logic that this will work but actually I'm working on the localhost so how Can change `www.mysite.com` with `localhost `

Comment: I added an update in the post above, please check and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I'm using windows and I don't want to modify a lot of files so is there any way to do it , just by modifying htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

What you need is mod_rewrite conditions matching value of `HTTP_REFERER`. Something like this (from the top of my head - may need some tweaking):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/?(\.html)?$ /splash.html [R,NC]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your /.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /splash.html [R,NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^products/?$ /index.php [R,L,NC]
```